# Get next fire time only by looking at cron expression

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I am running Quartz.NET as a service and I add my jobs directly in the `quartz-jobs.xml` file. So in order to add and delete jobs and triggers I deal with `Xml` and not the normal functions. 
I would like to know how can we get the next fire time of a trigger just by looking at its cron expression?

Comment: You can use NCrontab for parsing cron expressions http://www.raboof.com/projects/ncrontab/

Comment: @BenRobinson but does it also work with Quartz.NET style cron expressions? You know they have an extra parameter for seconds (I am not using them by the way).

Comment: No it only supports standard cron expressions. It does definitely have a GetNextOccurrence method that you run on a parsed expresion.

Comment: @BenRobinson you can post it as answer too.

Comment: DateTimeOffset? nextFireTimeUtc = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithCronSchedule(myCronExpression).Build().GetNextFireTimeUtc();

Comment: @MarkoLahma will give it a try and come back to you soon. This looks easier than installing a new library.

Comment: @BenRobinson only works with UNIX style expressions. Returns an error when I try to use a Quartz.NET style cron expressions. That is why I asked.

Comment: @MarkoLahma I am testing your solution for the following cron expression: "0 26 13 17 10 ? 2015" But it returns a nextfiretime of null. Why do you think that happens knowing this is a date in the future?

Comment: @Pedram - Please see my comment at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30876859/46249.  I just ran into this problem myself.  Per http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/cc03bb79-c0c4-6d84-3d05-a17f59727c98.htm, "The value returned is not guaranteed to be valid until after the Trigger has been added to the scheduler."  So make sure you call ScheduleJob(...) prior to executing `GetNextFireTimeUtc()'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the next fire time from given cron expression:

```
var expression = new CronExpression("0 26 13 17 10 ? 2015");
DateTimeOffset? time = expression.GetTimeAfter(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
```