# GetNextFireTimeUtc() returns null while trigger takes place in the futre

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I am trying to delete all the triggers that have expired because Quartz.NET crashes when it faces triggers that will never be fired. So I would like to know the next fire time of my triggers and if they do not have any, then they are expired and should be removed.
But now I am seeing that even a trigger that is in the future returns a `null` for its next fire time:

```
string expression = "0 26 13 17 10 ? 2015";
DateTimeOffset? nextFireTimeUtc = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithCronSchedule(expression).Build().GetNextFireTimeUtc();
```

As can be seen my cron expression is for 2015. But `nextFireTimeUtc` returns `null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get next fire time only by looking at cron expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400648/get-next-fire-time-only-by-looking-at-cron-expression)

Answer (score 6):

Just ran into this myself.  Per [Trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc Method](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/cc03bb79-c0c4-6d84-3d05-a17f59727c98.htm), "The value returned is not guaranteed to be valid until after the Trigger has been added to the scheduler."

So make sure you call `ScheduleJob(...)` prior to executing `GetNextFireTimeUtc()'.