# .Net Parsing Cron expression with 7 fields

Tags: .net, .net-core, cron

I'm using [this](https://github.com/juliacscai/jquery-cron-quartz) jquery plugin in my frontend in order to create a cron expression. 
It creates expressions like "0 0/20 * * * ? *".

I've tried a couple of packages in .net core (NCrontab and Cronos) but both of them don't recognize a seven field cron expression, I've also checked Quartz.Net docs and it does not support year field

Is there any package that can parse this expression? I've just have to get the next occurrence of the expression.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a reference for seven field cron expression? As I understand 6th field is year field. **1-Minutes 2-Hours 3-DayOfMonth 4-Month 5-DayOfWeek 6-Year**

Comment: The definition of the fields is 1-Seconds, 2-Minutes, 3-Hours, 4-Day Of Month, 5-Month, 6-Day Of Week 7-Year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) is solving this parsing as I`ve seen in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400648/get-next-fire-time-only-by-looking-at-cron-expression)
Thanks.